# How to implement JavaScript/ECMAScript "no LineTerminator here" rule in JavaCC?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, javacc

I continue working on my [JavaCC grammar](https://github.com/highsource/javascript-codemodel/blob/master/parser/src/main/javacc/ecmascript-262.jj) for [ECMAScript 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/Ecma-262.pdf). It actually goes quite well, I think I've covered most of the expressions now.

I have now two questions, both of them are related to the automatic semicolon insertion (§7.9.1). This is one of them.

The specification defines the following production:

```
PostfixExpression :
    LeftHandSideExpression
    LeftHandSideExpression [no LineTerminator here] ++
    LeftHandSideExpression [no LineTerminator here] --
```

**How can I implement a reliable "no LineTerminator here" check?**

For the record my `LINE_TERMINATOR` is at the moment something like:

```
SPECIAL_TOKEN :
{
    <LINE_TERMINATOR: <LF> | <CR> | <LS> | <PS> >
|   < #LF: "\n" > /* Line Feed */
|   < #CR: "\r" > /* Carriage Return */
|   < #LS: "\u2028" > /* Line separator */
|   < #PS: "\u2029" > /* Paragraph separator */
}
```

I have read about [lexical states](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/javacc-faq-moz.htm#tth_sEc3.11), but I am not sure if this is a right direction. I've checked a few other JavaScript grammars I have found, but did not find any similar rules there. (I actually feel myself a [total cargo culter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) when I try to overtake something from these grammars.)

I'd be grateful for a pointer, a hint or just a keyword for the right search direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think for the "restricted productions" you can do this

```
void PostfixExpression() : 
{} {
     LeftHandSideExpression() 
     (
         LOOKAHEAD( "++", {getToken(0).beginLine == getToken(1).beginLine})
         "++"
     |
         LOOKAHEAD( "--", {getToken(0).beginLine == getToken(1).beginLine})
         "--"
     |
         {}
     )
}
```

Comment: Hm, a very interesting idea. I'll try it out.

Comment: Or perhaps `getToken(0).endLine == getToken(1).beginLine`.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** As Gunther pointed out, my original solution was not correct due to this paragraph in 7.4 of the spec:

> Comments behave like white space and are discarded except that, if a MultiLineComment contains a line terminator character, then the entire comment is considered to be a LineTerminator for purposes of parsing by the syntactic grammar.

I'm posting a correction but leaving my original solution at the end of the question.

## Corrected solution

The core idea, as proposed by Theodore Norvell is to use semantic lookahead. However I have decided to implement a more safe check:

```
public static boolean precededByLineTerminator(Token token) {
    for (Token specialToken = token.specialToken; specialToken != null; specialToken = specialToken.specialToken) {
        if (specialToken.kind == EcmaScriptParserConstants.LINE_TERMINATOR) {
            return true;
        } else if (specialToken.kind == EcmaScriptParserConstants.MULTI_LINE_COMMENT) {
            final String image = specialToken.image;
            if (StringUtils.containsAny(image, (char)0x000A, (char)0x000D, (char)0x2028,
                    (char)0x2029)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And the grammar is:

```
expression = LeftHandSideExpression()
(
    LOOKAHEAD ( <INCR>, { !TokenUtils.precededByLineTerminator(getToken(1))} )
    <INCR>
    {
        return expression.postIncr();
    }
|   LOOKAHEAD ( <DECR>, { !TokenUtils.precededByLineTerminator(getToken(1))} )
    <DECR>
    {
        return expression.postDecr();
    }
) ?
{
    return expression;
}
```

So the `++` or `--` are considered here iff they are not preceded by a line terminator.

---

## Original solution

This **not** is how I finally solved it.

The core idea, as proposed by Theodore Norvell is to use semantic lookahead. However I have decided to implement a more safe check:

```
public static boolean precededBySpecialTokenOfKind(Token token, int kind) {
    for (Token specialToken = token.specialToken; specialToken != null; specialToken = specialToken.specialToken) {
        if (specialToken.kind == kind) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And the grammar is:

```
expression = LeftHandSideExpression()
(
    LOOKAHEAD ( <INCR>, { !TokenUtils.precededBySpecialTokenOfKind(getToken(1), LINE_TERMINATOR)} )
    <INCR>
    {
        return expression.postIncr();
    }
|   LOOKAHEAD ( <DECR>, { !TokenUtils.precededBySpecialTokenOfKind(getToken(1), LINE_TERMINATOR)} )
    <DECR>
    {
        return expression.postDecr();
    }
) ?
{
    return expression;
}
```

So the `++` or `--` are considered here iff they are not preceded by a line terminator.

Comment: Does it also handle the case where the line terminator is buried in a MultiLineComment? ECMA-262 specifies that it is disallowed in that case either.

Comment: @Gunther Good question. No, it probably does not. I'll check.

Comment: I guess that the original proposal would have covered that case, wouldn't it? A while ago I built something similar, when adding support for automatic semicolon insertion to [REx parser generator](http://bottlecaps.de/rex). You can find it by looking at method followsLineTerminator() in a parser generated from [EcmaScript.ebnf](http://bottlecaps.de/rex/EcmaScript.ebnf) with `-asi` turned on

Comment: @Gunther In principle, yes. However, it assumes that parsers understanding of the newline is the same like in the ES grammer. I'm not 100% this is the case. Therefore this other solution.

Comment: @Gunther You are right, I indeed had a bug there due to that part of the spec I was missing. Corrected now, please see the update. Thank you for your insight!